# How to define a global zero object of a class that can be passed to other classes? (C++)

Tags: c++, global-variables, default-constructor

I want to create an object with default values (zero initialization of all class variables) such that it is global and can be accessed/passed to other classes. Consider the following minimal working example, The class number is defined as follows:

```
//header1.hpp
template<class T>
class number{
    public:
    number(T& val):number_(val){};
    T number_;
};
```

and the class twiceNumber is initialized by an object of class Number by value. I want the default constructor just to take simply the default zero object from class number (see the question mark in the sample).

```
//header2.hpp
template<class T>
class twiceNumber{
    publice:
    twiceNumber ():twiceNumber(?);
    twiceNumber(number<T>& m):n(m);
    number<T>& n;
}
```

The main is

```
//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){
     twiceNumber<double> tryTwice;
     std::cout<<tryTwice.n.number_<<"\n";
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using default parameter values anywhere?

Comment: There are no "null" objects in C++. If you have a reference to an object, you must initialize it to an actual existing object. Perhaps you could solve your current problem by having a `number<T> zero;` object in the `twiceNumber` class, together with an `T default_Value{};` to initialize it with? Or perhaps the even better and more simple solution is to not use references at all, but copy the values or use plain default-initialization?

Comment: yes that helps but how to make it global? Otherwise, I need to add this `number<T> zero` to each class I make.

Comment: To be honest you probably don't want it to be global unless you also make it constant. Non-constant global information ain't the root of all evil, but it's a great way to get things started on the path to the darkside. Anyone anywhere can make changes at any time and that sort of chaos can lead to some really rough debugging.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is almost never use reference or constant class members.

Comment: @user4581301 Especially if that non-constant global is called "zero". Who knows what `number<int>::zero._number = 2;` will do to other algorithms?